# jquery changing button text color in dialog

Tags: jquery, text, colors, dialog

I created a close button inside a dialog using jquery and I am trying to change the color of text of a button in the dialog, I can change the color of the button and I can change the size of the text but when I try to change the color of the text nothing happens,

here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $("#Div1").dialog({
         title: "select ",

         width: 320,
         height: 340,
         dialogClass: 'myTitleClass',
         modal: true,
         appendTo: "form",
         buttons: {

             Close: function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }
         }
     });
 </script>


 </style>
.ui-button-text{
 background:green;    ------> changing the button color
 font-size:50px;      ------> changing the text button size
 color: #008CBA;      ------> doesn't change the text button color  
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: Can you add the html markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it:

```css
color: #008CBA !important;
```

As I see in the Developer Tools. You should use class:

```html
.ui-button {
..
}
```

Just try it